# Joining SQLsingle query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, llblgenpro

```
select * from ProjectFeature pf
inner join ProjectArea pa
on pa.AreaId = pf.AreaId
inner join Project p
on p.ProjectId = pa.ProjectId
where (p.ProjectId=175 AND pf.FeatureStatusTypeId=2
AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId])) AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId])))
```

I have another query

```
select * from ProjectFeature pf
inner join ProjectArea pa
on pa.AreaId = pf.AreaId
inner join Project p
on p.ProjectId = pa.ProjectId
where (p.ProjectId=175 AND pf.FeatureStatusTypeId=2
AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId])) AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.ChangeRequestToFeatureId) AS [FeatureId])))
```

the second query is exactly the same, but the function takes another field at the very end of the query

I have tried UNION Operator but LLBLGEN pro doesnt support UNION operator 
How can I make this int o a single query that retrieves both the resulsets?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from ProjectFeature pf
inner join ProjectArea pa
on pa.AreaId = pf.AreaId
inner join Project p
on p.ProjectId = pa.ProjectId
where (p.ProjectId=175 AND pf.FeatureStatusTypeId=2
AND ((pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId])) 
OR (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.ChangeRequestToFeatureId) AS [FeatureId]))))
```

Having removed redundance it is possible to reduce request

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the results as another row(s) under the same query, provided that they have exactly same columns and datatypes, then you can use [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) for the same:

```
select * from ProjectFeature pf
inner join ProjectArea pa
on pa.AreaId = pf.AreaId
inner join Project p
on p.ProjectId = pa.ProjectId
where (p.ProjectId=175 AND pf.FeatureStatusTypeId=2
AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId])) AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId])))
UNION
select * from ProjectFeature pf
inner join ProjectArea pa
on pa.AreaId = pf.AreaId
inner join Project p
on p.ProjectId = pa.ProjectId
where (p.ProjectId=175 AND pf.FeatureStatusTypeId=2
AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId])) AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.ChangeRequestToFeatureId) AS [FeatureId])))
```

Comment: Yes i have tried UNION but LLBLGEN pro doesnt support UNION operator

Comment: Check [this](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Linq/gencode_linq_remarkslimitations.htm) out for workarounds. Yea, LLBLGEN pro doesnt support `UNION` operator and you didn't say anywhere that you are using LLBLGEN pro.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a strange way to rewrite the query, but you can also try something like this:

```
select * 
from ProjectFeature pf
inner join ProjectArea pa
  on pa.AreaId = pf.AreaId
inner join Project p
  on p.ProjectId = pa.ProjectId
where 
(
  p.ProjectId=175 
  AND pf.FeatureStatusTypeId=2
  AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId])) 
  AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId]))
)
OR
(
  p.ProjectId=175 
  AND pf.FeatureStatusTypeId=2
  AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.FeatureId) AS [FeatureId])) 
  AND (pf.FeatureId IN (SELECT dbo.[MaxFeatureVersoinId](pf.ChangeRequestToFeatureId) AS [FeatureId]))
)
```

Place the two `WHERE` clauses in the same query with an `OR` between them.  Also in your first query you appear to be repeating the last line, I am not sure why you need to do that.